# How to convert HTML formatting inside google sheets rows to their correct formatted equivalent

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have been looking for a solution to convert a database I have with HTML formatting in one of the columns to its "normal" text equivalency in google sheets. A lot of the solutions I've found dealt with writing programs to do this or using Excel, so they unfortunately didn't pertain well enough.

For example in one of my columns I have;

`Fast (<i> This character deals damage before non-<b>Fast</b> characters in combat.</i>)`

But I would like to be able to have a somewhat streamlined solution to convert the above to:

Fast (*This character deals damage before non-**Fast** characters in combat.*)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, with Google Sheet API, you can only format text within a cell. As mentioned in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/conditional-format), conditional formatting lets you format cells so that their appearance changes dynamically according to the value they contain, or to values in other cells.

You may want to request new feature [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/support#missing_features).